# Qt Desktop Development

Tags: c++, qt

I have read on internet that Nokia is abandoning Qt desktop development, and in future it will no longer support desktop development and mobile development will be the only future of Qt. How much this news is authentic. Has Nokia changed its mind or they are going to implement this idea. And Has Nokia developed a standard Qt IDE for android development?

Comment: Providing a link to the information you read seems useful.  Otherwise, it's probably simplest for someone to provide an answer of "I read they weren't." and call it good.

Comment: Keep in mind that Qt is actually opensource, and Nokia is trying to grow external contributions.

Comment: @ qdot What kind of "External Contributions" you mean!

Comment: Code written by people outside Nokia :)

Comment: I'd break my Nokia phone to pieces if they actually do it. I love Qt :)

Answer (score 3):

Thousands of desktop applications are built on the Qt toolkit, so I find this irrealistic.

Just to name a big project, the whole KDE environment is Qt-based, so they will surely continue to work on it even if Nokia discontinued it - actually, they even [signed an agreement](http://www.kde.org/community/whatiskde/kdefreeqtfoundation.php) with Nokia to be allowed to re-release the Qt under a BSD-style license in case Nokia discontinued them. And anyhow, being the Qt libraries released also under the GPL license, anyone could pick up their development even if Nokia failed.

Answer (score 1):

None of it is officially true.

Nokia hasn't said anything about abandoning desktop support. But they also haven't said much about what their plans for Qt are.

However, they more or less consider desktop development a "solved problem". They're not going to make any major changes to that aspect of Qt.

However, they're not going to abandon it either. They need it. All their development tools are implemented in Qt, and they're very much desktop applications. So as long as Qt exists, Nokia will need Qt desktop support.

The question is whether (1) Nokia will abandon Qt entirely (how does it fit into their bet on Windows Phone?), and (2) how much *improvement* Qt desktop will see. It'll be supported, but there's no guarantee that it'll be significantly improved compared to where it is now.

Finally, don't forget that Qt is open source, and even if Nokia abandons it, there's nothing to stop others from contributing to the Qt project.

And some fairly big projects (KDE and Ubuntu) use various parts of Qt for desktop purposes. So even if Nokia decides to drop all involvement with Qt tomorrow, the project is unlikely to die.